# Route 53 DNS Routing over different API Gateway custom domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have for example 2 API Gateways with different custom domains working in 2 different regions,

NA:

- Custom Domain Name: us.api.example.com
- API Gateway domain name: APIGateway1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

EU:

- Custom Domain Name: eu.api.example.com
- API Gateway domain name: APIGateway2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

and for each custom domain, I followed the aws doc to create Type A record with simple Routing Policy

NA:

- Record Name: us.api.example.com
- Type: A
- Routing policy: Simple
- Value/Route traffic to: APIGateway1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

EU:

- Record Name: eu.api.example.com
- Type: A
- Routing policy: Simple
- Value/Route traffic to: APIGateway2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

They are both working fine

Now I want to do a Geolocation DNS routing like:

NA:

- Record Name: us.api.example.com
- Type: A
- Routing policy: Geolocation
- Value/Route traffic to: APIGateway1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- Location: NA
- 
- Record Name: us.api.example.com
- Type: A
- Routing policy: Geolocation
- Value/Route traffic to: APIGateway2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- Location: EU

Basically routing traffic from us.api.example.com to APIGateway2 for client in EU. This breaks the requirement "The API that you want to route traffic to must include a custom domain name, such as api.example.com that matches the name of the Route 53 record" mentioned in this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html

Want to have some help and suggestion to see if Route 53 DNS Routing over different API Gateway custom domains is really not able to achieve?

Comment: how did you solve the issue? did you register a domain for the `api-gateway` url in `route-53` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to use the wildcard custom domains: This works if your 2 API gateways are in different AWS regions:

APIG1 in us-east-1 (or anything other than APIG2's):

- custom domain name: *.my.api.com

APIG2 in us-west-2 (or anything other than APIG1's):

- custom domain name: *.my.api.com

Both custom domains should serve a certificate that allows all expected subdomains, You can use a wildcard certificate as well, `*.my.api.com`

Then you have hosted zone `my.api.com`

- CNAME Record `us-east-1.my.api.com` -> APIG1's endpoint
- CNAME Record `us-west-2.my.api.com` -> APIG2's endpoint
  I tested with round robin and it works:
- CNAME Record `round-robin.my.api.com` -> `us-east-1.my.api.com`
  (weight x) CNAME Record
- `round-robin.my.api.com` ->
  `us-west-2.my.api.com` (weight y)

I assume it also works if you do geographical routing.

**Unfortunately this doesn't work if you have more than one APIG in the same AWS region because the wildcard domain name is regional and must be unique per region. We are still looking for help with this**